# Error in Reading a txt file: Bad integer for item in list input

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I have this code to read numeric values that are saved by Fortran.  That data has 4800 rows and 19 column.

The head of this data looks like this

```
       1           2   1.50000000       0.00000000               1          21         240         361           2           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
       2           2   1.50000000       0.00000000               1          19         208         390           7           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
       3           2   1.50000000       0.00000000               1          13         181         419          11           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
       4           2   1.50000000       0.00000000               1          17         213         386           8           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
       5           2   1.50000000       0.00000000               1          18         215         389           2           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
       6           2   1.50000000       0.00000000               1          18         245         356           5           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
       7           2   1.50000000       0.00000000               1          17         205         395           7           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
       8           2   1.50000000       0.00000000               1          21         251         350           2           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
       9           2   1.50000000       0.00000000               1          17         207         385          15           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
      10           2   1.50000000       0.00000000               1          10         142         439          33           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
      11           2   1.50000000       0.00000000               1          19         249         353           3           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
```

The name of the columns are,  sim, infected, beta, epsilon.  The other 15 columns "countt" is just the simulation results.  I wrote this code to read the data in F90.

```
    program read
    implicit none 
     integer, dimension(4800,15)::countt
     integer :: i
    integer ,dimension(4800)::sim, infected,id
    real,dimension(4800):: epsilon, beta

 open(unit = 2, file = '/Dropbox/epi_data.txt', status = 'old', action = 'read')
  do i = 1,4800
 read(2,*) sim(i), infected(i), beta(i), epsilon(i),  countt(i,:)

  print*,  sim(i), infected(i), beta(i), epsilon(i),  countt(i,:)
end do
  close(2)

  end program read
```

Whenver I run this code, I get this error " Fortran runtime error: Bad integer for item 3 in list input
"

What am I missing here?

The other issue I have is, what should I do if I want to save  a training set by  by 100. I mean, save 100 rows and skip a 100, save a 100 and skip a 100 until the end of rows?
So at the end of my 4800rows, I will have 2400 for training set.

Do I need to upload the data for this question?

Comment: Do you have access to a modern Fortran (2008+) compiler? If so, I suggest you use the `newunit` specifier instead of hard-coding file identification units.

Comment: It is dangerous to use unit numbers below 10. Use 11 or larger or newunit.

Comment: I am very new to fortran, ( I started trying this language 4 weeks a go), but I will have a look to what you suggested. Thank you very much

Comment: After you updated the code you should probably also update the error message. Is it still item 3?

Comment: Great note!! Indeed thank you very much @VladimirF for your note. I went back to the error message and it says item 1 instead of 3 now, so I fixed that. The code runs fine now.

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, you can mark it as accepted as a courtesy and as a pointer for future visitors.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to read in the third column as integer values (`infected` is of type `integer`). However, `1.50000000` and the like are not formatted as integers (they are reals). Therefore the error.

You probably need to change the order of the columns or how you read them in, i.e. remove `id(i),`.

Comment: Thank you Alexander Vogt 

i did fix what you suggested, and I updated the code here but I still have the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much @Alexander .  the code works fine now based on your initial feedback.

Answer (score 0):

you have to reformat your *.txt file.

Fortran uses dot "." as a decimal separation, such as 1.50000000 is "1.5", not "150000000".

Comment: What makes you believe it should mean 150000000?

Comment: The text file was saved using Fortran itself. I am not sure if that could make a difference though. Here is a link to my entire txt file. https://www.dropbox.com/s/e7ztzwlz6n25dyj/epi_data.txt?dl=0